# Trying to get Redux app to display React elements (setup issue)

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to get async calls to work, but am stuck at a setup hurdle. I just read and replicated this async example, and then tried to copy some bits over into my app http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html

My app won't display any errors and React elements do not get put onto the DOM and I'm only able to display my index.html...

If someone could check out the client folder where the react code sits that would be amazing (index.html is in views folder in root, bundle is in public/javascripts)
https://github.com/jaegerbombb/twitter-api-test

No idea what's going wrong and am wondering how I might be able to debug this type of issue in the future

Extra info:

I started out with everything working (a button saying show all and another saying hide all, which displayed a string) inside the client/twitter folder. My additions were inside the Tweets folder and appComponent/index files

Comment: Will continue to check this every 10 minutes until I/someone figure's it out (or I give up), not sure if it's an issue with my getTweetContainer

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console ? Does the bundle file correctly loaded ?

Comment: Only this and my React toolbar says waiting for Root to load. I don't feel like this is helpful

```Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.invariant @ bundle.js:8671onlyChild......... ```

Comment: Start by setting the NODE_ENV to 'development' in your webpack config to see the real error.

Comment: I thought I did that.. will look again in a bit. Thanks

Comment: Aha two errors/warnings 

```Uncaught Invariant Violation: onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child.``` and
 ```Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Provider`, expected a single ReactElement. Check the render method of `App`.```

Comment: Not really sure how to fix them

Comment: Progress... ```Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {displayData, retrieveData}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `ShowTweetComponent`.```

Comment: And I'm still stuck

Comment: Sort of fixed it when I removed combineReducers... no idea why